# How to send a URL request to a server without expecting a response back in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, send

I am using a VoIP softswitch. In order to trigger a call I have to send the call parameters (user/pass/phone#) via http to a URL without being redirected to that URL.
I tried JavaScript FORM with GET but I had no success.

Answer (score 2):

The request is not really relevant, the *response* is:

When the server responds with a 204 No Content (instead of the usual 200 OK), the browser stays on the original page. [See e.g. this](http://benramsey.com/archives/http-status-204-no-content-and-205-reset-content/).

Comment: +1 Very interesting, do browsers tend to change the URL in the address bar, or behave properly and just remain where they are?

Comment: Very useful, I shall use that in future.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an asynchronous request (AJAX).

This is substantially easier if you use a framework that provides the facility, for instance [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  Or you can do it directly, find a good tutorial ([example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro2/)).

Comment: I have *no* idea why this was marked down when identical to other comments and is a perfectly valid answer for the question given the mention of JavaScript methods.